# Write the name tag of an element JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

I am making a custom HTML5/JQuery Audio Player and I have my audio tags named like `name="Song Name"` and I want to use JQuery to grab that name tag value and write it in a `<p></p>` tag.  But whenever it runs it just says `[object Object]` instead of the name value.

**HTML**

```
<p id="song-name"></p>
<audio name="Song 1" src="/song1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<audio name="Song 2" src="/song2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<audio name="Song 3" src="/song3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

**JQuery**

```
var songName = $("audio[name]")

$("#song-name").text(songName);
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jaketr00/7afjLfL1/)

Comment: You have three audio tag, which tag are you looking for?

Comment: @Arvind I would like it to show the one that is currently playing when it gets triggered.  I have it set up to get triggered when someone clicks `play`, `skip`, or when it automatically goes to the next song.

Comment: $(".audio-player").eq(z).attr("name")

Comment: @NickMaroulis This works perfectly if i replace the `songName` variable to that.  just add it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the name value you need to call the `attr` call and get by name.

```
var songName = $("audio[name]").attr("name")
```

You were setting that variable to the Jquery object which just will have a text value of `[object Object]`.

Comment: This works for the first song, but when I go to the next song it keeps the name of the first song.  Is there any way to make it update to the current song that is playing?

Comment: Here I modded it to get the current song. http://jsfiddle.net/7afjLfL1/1/ . You need to reset it when you change songs like I did inside your play function.

Answer (score 0):

`$('audio[name]')` gave you all the three audio selectors, need to do each loop to get each audio name's value.

There are 3 audio tags

```
$('audio[name]').eq(0).attr('name');
$('audio[name]').eq(1).attr('name');
$('audio[name]').eq(2).attr('name');
```

**JS**

```
$('audio[name]').each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('name')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try handler instead:

For audio name starting with `Song`:

```
$(function(){
  $('audio[name^=Song]').on('play', fuction() {
    $('#song-name').text(this.name);
  });
});
```

OR

For any audio:

```
$(function(){
  $('audio').on('play', fuction() {
    $('#song-name').text(this.name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$(".audio-player").eq(z).attr("name")
```